# Explanation about proof of a continuity theorem for the inverse of a function.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, limits

Theorem: Let $ D\subset \mathbb{R} $ a compact subset and  a continuous  injective function $f$. Then the inverse function of $ f, f^{-1}: f(D)\rightarrow D $ define by $ f^{-1}(f(x))= x$ is a continuous function.

Proof: Only need proof $ f(V) $ is open set $ \forall x\in D$

Let $ V\subset D $ open, then $ D-V $ is closed set

As $ D $ is compact, then $ D-V $ is compact\
As $ f $ is continuous function then $ f(D-V) $ is closed set
As $ D $ is compact, then $ D-V $ is compact.
As $ f $ is continuous then $ f(D-V) $ is compact.
As $ f $ is injective, then $ f(D-V)=f(V^{c})=(f(V))^{c} $ then $ f(V) $ is open.

My question is this, because is sufficient prove $ f(V) $ is open set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument starts out well, but then develops some gaps (and has some repetitions).

Since $D-V$ is closed and $D$ is compact, $D-V$ is compact (good so far).

Since $f$ is a continuous function and $D-V$ is compact, $f(D-V)$ is **compact**.

Since compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are closed, $f(D-V)$ is **closed**.

Since $f$ is injective, $f(D-V)=f(V^c)=(f(V))^c$. Therefore $f(V)$ is open.

This completes the proof that "if $V$ is open then $f(V)$ is open".

Since $f$ is injective we can reword this to say "if $V$ is open then $(f^{-1})^{-1} (V)$ is open", which by definition means that $f^{-1}$ is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

I think is due to the theorem that says: "Let $U ⊂ R^n$ be open. A function $f : U → R^m$ is continuous (at all points in U) if and only if for each open $V ⊂ R^m$, the preimage $f^{−1}(V)$ is also open.", if you are interested in the proof of this theorem, you could find it at Theorem 1.2, here: http://www3.nd.edu/~jdiller/teaching/archive/fall14_20850/continuity.pdf

Comment: yes thanks,i think so